# how to create self signed certificate on Windows 7

Tags: ldap, azure-active-directory, self-signed

Iam in the process of creating a domain joined hdinsight cluster for which we need to have a valid ldap certificate from the issuing authority or create a self signed certificate.

But when trying to create the self signed certificate on the local machine ( windows 7 enterprise ) it fails with the following error:

The term 'new-self signed certificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.New-SelfSignedCertificate <<<<  -Subject *.abc.onmicrosoft.com -NotAfter $lifetime.AddDays(365) -KeyUsage DigitalSignature, KeyEncipherment -Type SSLServerAuthentication -DnsName *.abc.onmicrosoft.com CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (New-SelfSignedCertificate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap

Please help as how to create a self signed certificate in windows 7, I have tried downloading windows sdk but installation fails.

Answer (score 0):

See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/08/14/rsa-key-blocking-is-here/ for instructions on using certreq.exe to make self signed certs.